# How to update the software of an unrooted device? (Error Message)

Tags: unrooting

My device is recently unrooted, so I decided to update the software of my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3V (SM-T116BU) but this error message (The operating system on your device is modified in  an unauthorized way...) **always shows up** each time I tried to update the software even though I have unrooted my device. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

did you try with "Smart Switch" program from your PC, and download the update from there? As I saw in the video, you have to download the program, and check the latest update for your phone when connecting via USB. You can check this video, I think you can solve your problem by this way.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRDyAlqIrhU

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue of the tripped dm-verity / etc. counters, I would suggest that you refer to or post up at www.xda-developers.com for further help on that.  Assuming there is a current method to reset the counters, that *should* allow for OTA updates to work again.

For OTA updates you aren't able to install in the mean time, I believe you can download them directly from Sammobile (reputable source).  [This page](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-tab3-lite/SM-T116BU/) is for the model tablet you disclosed, please choose accordingly for your carrier.  If you need further assistance, let us know!  Good luck.